# How to retrieve Firestore documents based on array of document references in another document using AngularFire?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I'm working with Cloud Firestore in my project, and I have a collection "A" with a field "bRefs" that contains document references to multiple documents in another collection "B". Now, I want to retrieve all the documents from "B" that are referenced in the "bRefs" field of a specific document in "A".

I'm aware that using `getAll()` or fetching all the documents and then filtering them based on their references might not be the most efficient way to do this, especially if the collection "B" has a large number of documents.

Is there a more efficient way to query Firestore to achieve this?

What I want to achieve is similar to the following TypeScript code:

```js
getBs(bRefs: DocumentReference<B>[]) {
  return this.fstore.collection<B>('b',
    ref => ref.where('someField (missing part)', 'in', bRefs)
  ).get();
}
```

Comment: "especially if the collection "B" has a large number of documents" The number of documents in a collection has no influence on query performance. That's Firestore's performance guarantee.

Comment: So you're looking to read the array that contains document references and then get the corresponding documents in one go? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

Having documents references in a document doesn't mean that have the actual documents. Those references are only some paths to the documents. If you need to read the content of those documents, you have to read them explicitly. So there is no way you can read the document along with the other documents where the references are pointing to in a single go. You have to perform separate requests.